# Contraction of would

Tags: pronunciation, contractions

In casual speech, can you contract "would you" to "dju" in questions like these:

What'd you like to drink?

What flavor'd you like?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. Just because my friend might, that doesn't mean I would. Unfortunately this site isn't good for polling. You'd be better off converting this into a "can you" question instead, at which point the answer is technically "yes", no further explanation needed.

Comment: What you show is how I'd probably do it.  Partly it would depend on how hard I was trying to convey a given accent, though.

Answer (score 1):

The "y" sound in "you" can trigger a process called [palatalization](https://www.britannica.com/topic/palatalization) in a preceding consonant in rapid speech, causing it to be pronounced closer to the roof of the mouth. You can in fact see this in any word ending in "d" or "t" followed by a word beginning in "y", where the "d" will be pronounced like a "j", and a "t" will be pronounced like a "ch" in rapid or casual speech. This same process is also why you don't see a "d", "t", "s", or "z" sound followed by a "y" sound within any words in American English.

Comment: I think the exact phonetic process should be termed 'assibilation' as the result is a fusion  /sibilant/.